# Android - avoid exponential in string to double conversion

Tags: android, string, double, type-conversion

I trying to get value from edittext and stored as string. Then it converts to double. While converting up to 7 characters functioning normally but if i try to add more than 7 result is 1.23456789E8. Here is my code

```
String value = txtData.txtSearch.getText().toString();
// value = "987654321.45"

double amount1 = Double.parseDouble(value);
// amount1 = 9.8765432145E8

double amount2 = 0.05;

double result = (amount1 * amount2) / 100;
// result = 4.3827160725E14
```

after calculation i got 4.3827160725E14 which is not correct correct answer is 493827.16

How can i get correct value without losing precision?

Comment: try long instead of double

Answer (score 3):

I solved it. i use BigDecimal instead of double now my code is

```
String value = txtData.txtSearch.getText().toString();
// value = "987654321.45"

BigDecimal amount1 = new BigDecimal(value);
// amount1 = "987654321.45"

BigDecimal amount2 = new BigDecimal(0.05);

BigDecimal result = (amount1.multiply(amount2)).divide(new BigDecimal(100));
result = result.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
// result = 493827.16
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives your expected result:

```
public class DoubleTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      double amount1 = Double.parseDouble("987654321.45");
      double amount2 = 0.05;
      double result = (amount1 * amount2) / 100;
      System.out.println(result);
 }
}
```

So, are you sure that you're getting the value that you think you are from `txtData.txtSearch.getText().toString();` ?

By the way, if you're really interested in arbitrary precision (e.g. when dealing with money), use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
double result = (amount1 * amount2) / 100.0;
string resultInMyFormat =  new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do you avoid exponential in string to double conversion?

I think we are all missing the point here.

Here is your example:

```
// value = "987654321.45"

double amount1 = Double.parseDouble(value);
// amount1 = 9.8765432145E8
```

Presumably, the stuff in comments was printed; e.g. using a debugger or calls to `println`.

So why are you seeing exponential / scientific notation?

Well it is NOT due to the way that the string was parsed to a `double`.  It is actually happening when the `double` is converted *back* to a string in order to print it.  Example:

```
$ cat Test.java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "987654321.45";
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(value);
        System.out.println(amount);
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.########");
        System.out.println(format.format(amount));
    }
}
$ java Test
9.8765432145E8
987654321.45
```

See?  I started with "987654321.45", converted it to a `double`.  Then printed it two different ways.   And got two different string representations *for the same `double` value*

---

So why does `println(double)` print the number like that?

Well ...

1. `System.out` is a `PrintStream`
2. `println(double)` is equivalent to `print(double)` followed by `println()`
3. `print(double)` converts the `double` to a `String` using `String.valueOf(double)`
4. `valueOf(double)` returns the same representation as `Double.toString(double)`
5. `toString(double)` is specified to use scientific notation if the *magnitude* of the number is less than 10<sup>-3</sup> or greater or equal to 10<sup>7</sup>.

This is *all* specified in the respective javadocs.  The most salient is the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) for `toString(double)`.

---

If you don't believe me, you can check the Java Language Specification, and the IEE 754 Standard for floating point representations; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

If you want to, you can even use `Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double)` to examine the bit representation of a `double` value.

---

Finally

> After calculation i got `4.3827160725E14` which is not correct correct answer is `493827.16`.

When I repeat that calculation I get the answer `493827.1607250001` ... using `System.out.println(double)`.   (Note that there is no scientific notation ... because the number is less than 10<sup>7</sup>. )

The exact answer for the calculation (1987654321.45 * 0.05) / 100 493827.160725.  The difference between the the exact answer and what Java gives us is caused by computer floating point *rounding error* .  It happens  because the IEE 754 representation is actually binary representation with a binary mantissa and a binary exponent, and because the mantissa has a fixed number of binary digits of precision.

This rounding error is inherent to calculations using IEE 754 representations.  If you want to mitigate it, you can use `BigDecimal` to represent your numbers.  But you should be aware that even `BigDecimal` is not precise:

- You can't represent Pi or any other irrational number precisely using `BigDecimal`.
- Many rational numbers don't have a precise representation as a `BigDecimal`; e.g. the value of 1.0 / 3.0.

So you still (in theory) need to be concerned with rounding errors with `BigDecimal`.