# How to get float value from json?

Tags: android, json, web-services, double

i am retrieving value from jsondata

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
HttpResponse response;
HttpGet gett = new HttpGet(URL);

response = client.execute(get);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new putStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
orignalResponse = reader.readLine();

JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(orignalResponse);
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(tokener);
Log.v("AMOUNT", "amount :"+jsonData.get("Amount"));
```

I want Retrieve "Amount" which originally is "23868352383.00"
but while i am retrieving it using

`jsonData.get("Amount")`, it gives value as "2.3868352383E10",

using `jsonData.getDouble("Amount")`, it gives value as "2.3868352383E10"

using `jsonData.getLong("Amount")` it removes fraction part

How can i retrieve the value ?? please help.

Comment: I suggest you to fetch it like String only and then convert it whatever you want. But just get from Json as a String.

Comment: json always give Sting  we can parse String to Float

Comment: i already tried that but getting as string it also gives the value as "2.3868352383E10",
is there any other way ?

Comment: @RajeshSuthar No its not possible, if your value in JSon is "23868352383.00" then it must returns same String what it is.

Comment: @pratt : it is giving like this "2.3868352383E10"

Comment: @RajeshSuthar ar you sure you getting value as a String

Comment: This is my full response : {"Amount":23868352383.00,"TotalAmt":119344119.91,"UserID":1.0}

Comment: @RajeshSuthar Show me your code where you fetching "Amount"

Comment: @pratt: please check it in above code, it is in log statement

Log.v("AMOUNT", "amount :"+jsonData.get("Amount"));

Comment: @RajeshSuthar Ya code is fine, then also not getting proper response?

Comment: @pratt: no, not getting

Comment: @RajeshSuthar write jsonData.getString("Amount"); It will work

Comment: @pratt: i already tried it but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try **Big Decimal** to convert your string to float removing exponents

check [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970422/android-avoid-exponential-in-sting-to-double-conversion)

```
           BigDecimal.valueOf(yourvalueString);
```

Hope it Help.

You can get the further help from [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-convert-exponential-decimal-double-number/)
Thanks

Answer (score 13):

The BigDecimal class has a method [`floatValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#floatValue--). So, If you want to get rather float than String that you can also use it.

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(jsonObject.getDouble("KEY_STRING")).floatValue();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(jsonData.getDouble("Amount")).toPlainString()
```

Comment: i tried this but it removes fraction part, will you please check it by your side using this value "2.3868352383E10"

Comment: It removed the fraction because its value is zero, try changing the value "23868352383.00" to "23868352383.90" for example , you will see that it is working

Answer (score 4):

Simply use this:

```
float value = Float.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("KEY_STRING"));
```

Answer (score 0):

how to get float values like that 1.5 from json 
my float number from json look like that :"rating"  : 4.5,

and my code in android studio i get this float value by writing:

float ratingNumber  = BigDecimal.valueOf (hit.getDouble("rating")).floatValue();

it is work fine for me